# the right way to return a Single from a CompletionStage

Tags: cassandra, rx-java2, cassandra-3.0, micronaut, rx-java3

I'm playing around with reactive flows using RxJava2, Micronaut and Cassandra. I'm new to rxjava and not sure what is the correct way to return a of List Person in the best async manner?

data is coming from a Cassandra Dao interface

```
public interface PersonDAO {    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM cass_drop.person;")
    CompletionStage<MappedAsyncPagingIterable<Person>> getAll(); 
}
```

that gets injected into a micronaut controller

> ```
>    return Single.just(personDAO.getAll().toCompletableFuture().get().currentPage())
>             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
>             .map(people -> HttpResponse.ok(people));
> ```

OR

> ```
> return Single.just(HttpResponse.ok())
>         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
>         .map(it -> it.body(personDAO.getAll().toCompletableFuture().get().currentPage()));
> ```

OR switch to RxJava3

> ```
>     return Single.fromCompletionStage(personDAO.getAll())
>             .map(page -> HttpResponse.ok(page.currentPage()))
>             .onErrorReturn(throwable -> HttpResponse.ok(Collections.emptyList()));
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Not a pro of RxJava nor Cassandra :

In your first and second example, you are blocking the thread executing the `CompletionStage` with `get`, even if you are doing it in the IO thread, I would not recommand doing so.

You are also using a `Single` wich can emit, only one value, or an error. Since you want to return a `List`, I would sugest to go for at least an `Observable`.

Third point, the result from Cassandra is paginated, I don't know if it's intentionnaly but you list only the first page, and miss the others.

I would try a solution like the one below, I kept using the IO thread (the operation may be costly in IO) and I iterate over the pages Cassandra fetch :

```java
    /* the main method of your controller */
    @Get()
    public Observable<Person> listPersons() {
        return next(personDAO.getAll()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    private Observable<Person> next(CompletionStage<MappedAsyncPagingIterable<Person>> pageStage) {
        return Single.fromFuture(pageStage.toCompletableFuture())
                .flatMapObservable(personsPage -> {
                    var o = Observable.fromIterable(personsPage.currentPage());
                    if (!personsPage.hasMorePages()) {
                        return o;
                    }
                    return o.concatWith(next(personsPage.fetchNextPage()));
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you ever plan to use **reactor** instead of **RxJava**, then you can give [cassandra-java-driver-reactive-mapper](https://github.com/pPanda-beta/cassandra-java-driver-reactive-mapper) a try.

The syntax is fairly simple and works in compile-time only.